# XAMPP MySQL lower_case_table_names=2 works until MySQL restart

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm having an issue with changing MySQL `lower_case_table_names=2` (I  have also tried changing this to 0 but hasn't made any difference) on Windows 10 XAMPP.

I have some tables that need to have upper-case names, so set lower_case_table_names to 2 in my.ini under [mysqld]. I then set up my database (e.g. Accounts), then my tables (e.g. Users) and all works fine. However if I restart the MySQL server, open the database and table and I get the following error:

```
1146 - Table 'accounts.users' doesn't exist
```

**Note:** the conversion to lower-case in the message.

Do I need to change any other settings anywhere?

I am using MySQL 5.6.21.

Comment: Can you post results for `show databases` and `show tables`?

Comment: what is the previous value of `lower_case_table_names`?

Comment: @Shadow, no this post didn't solve my issue, I also tried changing lower_case_table_names to 0, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @DylanSu there was no value in the my.ini settings, but it defaults to 1.